# Trying to run batch file in powershell remotely is not working

Tags: selenium, batch-file, cmd, webdriver, powershell-remoting

I am currently administering a Selenium Grid with 20 remote PCs acting as nodes to a single Hub located on a server. At the moment I have to remote in to each machine when I want to restart the hub or nodes and clear up any stale chromedriver or chrome instances. I am trying to automate this process via Powershell.

So far I have manage to write the ps scripts to kill any instances of chrome, chromedriver and java on the PCs and then restart the hub or node. They work when started locally on each machine when but fail when I try and execute them via a PSSession.

I have enabled remote sessions on each machine successfully and I can Invoke-Commands that will kill the existing instances of java and chrome but I can't restart the hub or nodes.

Example of Hub powershell script:

```
#This script kills any existing java process and runs StartHub.bat
Set-Location C:\Selenium
kill -Name java -Force -PassThru -ErrorAction Continue
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Selenium\StartHub.bat" -PassThru -Verbose
```

The bat file is as follows:

```
java -jar C:\Selenium\selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -role hub -hubConfig "V:\ServerFiles\hubconfig.json"
```

I have been testing with the execution policy unrestricted and my network administrator has changed GPO's to allow my to start java processes remotely but it's just not working. I've tried several approaches which I have listed below:

1: Entering a PSSession on remote server and calling the ps1 file:

```
C:\RestartHub.ps1
```

The result being that the existing hub instance is killed but a new one does not open.

2: I have then tried to Start a job with a ScriptBlock calling the cmd script to start the batch file:

```
Set-Location C:\Selenium
kill -Name java -Force -PassThru -ErrorAction Continue
Start-Job -ScriptBlock{cmd /c start "C:\Selenium\StartHub.bat"} -Name Hub -Verbose
```

This again kills the existing hub instance but the start script does not run or fails silently.

I have looked through the security logs on the remote machine to see if there are any issues there but the PSSession seems to be correct using the right user with full admin rights.

I have also changed the `ExecutionPolicy` on the remote machine to `restricted` to see if an access denied error is display, which it was. I changed back to `unrestricted` and error went away.

I'd be grateful for any ideas.

Comment: Have you tried setting the current location in the ScriptBlock? `-ScriptBlock{Set-Location "C:\Selenium"; cmd /c start "C:\Selenium\StartHub.bat"}`

Comment: I changed the bat file to: `java -jar C:\Selenium\selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -role hub -hubConfig "V:\ServerFiles\hubconfig.json"` and I can start the hub locally but not via a remote session. I'll edit to question to represent this

Answer (score 1):

`Start-Process` will start a process from an executable, you cannot use a bat file as an executable, `-FilePath` expects an executable's path
See below,

```
Start-Process cmd -Argumentlist "C:\Selenium\StartHub.bat" -PassThru -Verbose
```